# Getting 'Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError' in Selenium Script

Tags: automated-testing, selenium-webdriver, appium, mobile-automation

This is my selenium code. After I ran this code, I am getting a java.lang.AbstractMethodError.

```
package amazon;
import io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver; 
import java.io.File;
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.CapabilityType;
import org.openqa.selenium.remote.DesiredCapabilities;

public class StartApplication {

private static AndroidDriver driver;

public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException, InterruptedException {

        File app = new File("C:\\Users\\Dexter\\Desktop\\Appium\\AmazonTest\\com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping.apk");

        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities.setCapability(CapabilityType.BROWSER_NAME, "");
        capabilities.setCapability("deviceName", "Samsung Galaxy J7");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformVersion", "8.1.0");
        capabilities.setCapability("platformName", "Android");
        capabilities.setCapability("app", app.getAbsolutePath());
        capabilities.setCapability("appPackage", "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping");
        capabilities.setCapability("appActivity", "com.amazon.mShop.home.web.MShopWebGatewayActivity");

        driver = new AndroidDriver(new URL("https://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:xxxx/wd/hub"), capabilities);
        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(80, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
        Thread.sleep(3000);
         driver.quit();

  }

}
```

Following is the error, I am getting -

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.AbstractMethodError: org.openqa.selenium.remote.internal.ApacheHttpClient.execute(Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpRequest;)Lorg/openqa/selenium/remote/http/HttpResponse;
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:105)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:74)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:136)
    at io.appium.java_client.remote.AppiumCommandExecutor.execute(AppiumCommandExecutor.java:69)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:552)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:40)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.execute(AndroidDriver.java:1)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:213)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.<init>(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
    at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.<init>(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:36)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:114)
    at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.<init>(AppiumDriver.java:132)
    at io.appium.java_client.android.AndroidDriver.<init>(AndroidDriver.java:92)
    at amazon.StartApplication.main(StartApplication.java:32)
```

If anybody has any solution, kindly let me know.

Comment: I think this is caused by version inconsistency between your `AndroidDriver` version and your Appium server.

Comment: can you suggest any specific version I can use to fix this issue? @AlexeyR.

Answer (score 1):

You are getting errors from your `Appium` backend that are causing the http requests that your `Selenium` drivers are trying to make.

I would check the `Appium` backend is running and allows connections from your client.

Possible reasons for it not running :

- driver versions don't match - the `Android Driver` might need
  updating
- device is not connected/visible - the actual device might not be visible.
- `Appium` isn't running  - restart `Appium` and check the logs

You can test your backend is working by running `Appium` studio and using its `GUI`.

You can also do a lot of those things within exception handlers which could attempt retries or at least give you more information.

I will never understand why people think its sensible to write `Selenium` tests in `Java`; compiled languages make this so much harder and can add 10s of thousands to project costs.